# removing whitespace from dataframe titles

Tags: python, dataframe

I am trying to remove whitespace from the titles of columns on a dataframe.

```
my_df=pd.DataFrame({'  name_1':[1, 2],'  name_2':[3, 4],})
```

After some research, i've tried:

```
my_df.columns.map(lstrip())
df.columns.to_series().map(lstrip)
```

these both give:

NameError: name 'lstrip' is not defined

even though mystr.lstrip() works fine.

how can I do this without getting the name error? and why am I getting it?

Comment: The implementation is wrong. In your case ```my_df.columns.map(lstrip())```; lstrip() is passed as an argument to map() function, which is incorrect. The correct usage is: ```my_df.columns.str.lstrip()```. Or if you want to remove leading/trailing white space use [strip](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/strip.html) method without any arguments: ```my_df.columns.str.strip()```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lstrip` is a method of the `str` class, therefore `lstrip()` alone is going to produce that error while `str.lstrip()` or `mystr.lstrip()` (whit mystr being a string) won't.

So, you can use

```
my_df.columns.map(str.lstrip)
```

but because *pandas* has vecorized versions of the str methods under `pandas.Series.str`, is considered more pythonic (pandastic?) to use instead `my_df.columns.str.lstrip()`.

As noted by @saad_saeed in their comment, using `.strip()` instead of `.lstrip()` is recommended to eliminate both trailing and leading whitespaces, which are a common source of `KeyError`.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
my_df.columns = my_df.columns.str.strip()
```